# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my LinkedList insertion method in C

Tags: c

The segmentation fault occurs at the line "else if(head -> next == NULL){".
I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about pointers.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

void insert(Node* head, int value){
    if(head == NULL){
        head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        head -> value = value;
        head -> next = NULL;
    }else if(head -> next == NULL){
        printf("good\n");
        head -> next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        head -> next -> value = value;
        head -> next -> next = NULL;
    }else{
        insert(head -> next, value);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Node* head;
    head = NULL;
    insert(head, 3);
    insert(head, 4);
    printf("%d\n", head -> value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not support _methods_. C++ is a different languages.

Comment: And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Its a c program I didn't mean to tag this as c++

Comment: Step through the code **carefully** and use a debugger. The error is soooo obvious!

Comment: Yes, Use a debugger. You'll find the problem in less than 2 minutes if you use a debugger effectively.

Comment: I'm a beginner to c so it's not so obvious lol

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments.*

Comment: `printf("%d\n", head -> value);` <<- `head` is `NULL`

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you all

Comment: Basically, you are passing a memory location (NULL), which you obviously can't use  for much. So then in your function you create a new memory location, and then do nothing.  If you wanted to implement a linked list without returning an arguments, you could either pass a pointer to the pointer to Node, or, you could initialize the head in your main function, and then in your insert function, you append to it. But the head variable will obviously always remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The actual segmentation fault is happening in `main`, not in `insert`.  The problem is that, in `main`, you are never updating `head`.  It is initialized to `NULL`, and it remains `NULL` after both calls to `insert`.  The segmentation fault occurs when you attempt to dereference it in the `printf`:

```
printf("%d\n", head -> value);
```

Since `head` is `NULL`, you are getting a segmentation fault.

The problem is that `insert` is only updating its own local copy of `head`.  This change is not reflected in the caller, i.e. `main`.

The reason you're never seeing "good" printed from `insert` is that you're always passing a `NULL` value for `head` when calling `insert`.

There are two common ways to fix this.  One is to change `insert` to always return a pointer to the new list head.  The caller then updates its list head with the return value, e.g.

```
head = insert(head, 3);
```

The other is to change insert to take a *pointer* to the head pointer, and to modify it before returning.  So your call would look like:

```
insert(&head, 3);
```

And the prototype for `insert` would look like

```
void insert(Node **head_ptr, int value)
```

Within `insert`, the caller's copy of `head` would be updated by doing:

```
*head_ptr = head;
```

Either solution will solve your problem.